# mail activity window in el capitan

Tags: mail.app, macos

Since upgrading to el capitan a couple of days ago, activity window in mail does not work. I do receive emails, but can no longer see or check mail through the activity window when i want, have to wait for 'whenever'; clicking 'get mail' does not work on my demand.

I am on a MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2012)

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The Activity window shows for me (you could try under Window tab and click Activity).But I can't "Send it to Back" like before; now it is always the top window in the stack.